# Saving diacritics to mysql from pdf form

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, diacritics

I am submitting data from a PDF form to a MySQL database with php. Database, tables, MySQL is set to utf8_unicode_ci and when i submit diacritics from a browser form everything is fine.
Problem appears when i do it from PDF. I found out its pretty impossible to make PDF work with unicode. Is there a workaround for this? I'm having problems with the following chars: ă î ș ț â.

Comment: It would help greatly if you gave more specifics about the data pathway for your pdf submit.  Are you using FDF? Can you give a simple example?

Comment: after the pdf form is filled i am submitting data into the mysql database with a php script that is getting values from the pdf form with post method. I use FDF on retrieving data into the form but that's another story. I'm interested for now on this simple submission...how could i make those characters save correctly from PDF into the database.